# userEvent.type shuffles the letters for textarea

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

In my app I have this test:

```js
  it("changes the state when the author input is changed", () => {
    let inputBody = screen.getByRole("textbox", { name: "Your Comment" });
    userEvent.type(inputBody, "My Comment");
    expect(inputBody.value).toEqual("My Comment");
  });
```

This is the actual code in React:

```js
import React from "react";
import useInput from "../hooks/useInput";

const CommentForm = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const { value: author, reset: resetAuthor, bind: bindAuthor } = useInput("");
  const { value: body, reset: resetBody, bind: bindBody } = useInput("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmit({ author, body }, resetInputs);
  };
  const resetInputs = () => {
    resetAuthor();
    resetBody();
  };
  return (
    <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2>Post a Comment</h2>
      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="author">Your Name</label>
        <input id="author" type="text" {...bindAuthor} name="author" />
      </div>

      <div className="input-group">
        <label htmlFor="body">Your Comment</label>
        <textarea
          id="body"
          name="body"
          cols="30"
          rows="10"
          {...bindBody}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CommentForm;
```

What I am getting is :

```
   Expected: "My Comment"
    Received: "y CommentM"
```

So the letters are shuffled with no apparent reason (the first and the last letter). It works fine for the input but for the text area it goes crazy.

Here is the "bind"

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const useInput = (initialValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  return {
    value,
    reset: () => setValue(initialValue),
    bind: {
      value,
      onChange: (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      },
    },
  };
};

export default useInput;
```

Edit: I have added the whole CommentForm component. I have no idea why this behaves as is. Can it be due to some library versions?

Comment: Can you edit your question with what you've defined bindBody to be? I suspect this to be the issue as I've replicated everything else and it works as suspected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still facing this problem but the solution that worked for me was provided by Nick McCurdy in issue #391 of the [testing-library/user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/391) repository.

> "You can work around this by installing `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` and adding `--env jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` to the test script until CRA is updated with Jest 26 support."

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated the above code (minus `bindBody`) and it runs perfectly which leads me to believe it's whatever you've defined `bindBody` to be. Investigate this (or update your initial question for further investigation).

Also note - there's a discrepancy between what you're typing in the input and asserting on, you're typing `"MyComment"` and expecting `"My Comment"` (note the space).

Comment: I have edited original...it is not bind as it doesn't work without it as well on my machine.

Comment: I'm really struggling to replicate your issues (I've even added bindBody now). I can only suggest adding more code to your question (the code in which your text area is defined would be good)

Comment: Edited - added CommentForm component

Comment: Replicated the latest and still no error. I will say, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the custom `useInput` hook as it seems to be overcomplicating it just to save a few lines of code. I can't for the life of me figure out why the text value would be reversed...